# I want to see what queries have been run in an uncommitted transaction

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to see what queries have been run in an uncommitted transaction?

I tried Sp_who2 but I want to see the full query of the uncommitted trans.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to see what queries have been run in an uncommitted transaction?

No.  You can see the [locks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-tran-locks-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) that are still held by the session, which will give you some indication.  But without a Trace/XEvent you can't see all the queries.